# asp.net core - pass several parameters to custom authorization policy provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-authorization

I'm attempting to setup a custom policy provider in asp.net core.  I need to pass in several custom authorization attributes to the provider but struggling with how to do so.

I have it setup to accept one enum array currently and is working fine.  However, I would like to add 2 more enum arrays as additional, optional parameters to the authorization attribute.

Attribute as it is now:

```
[LEMClaimAuthorize(new ELocation[] { ELocation.Indy, ELocation.Columbus })]
```

Would like for it to work like so:

```
[LEMClaimAuthorize(new ELocation[] { ELocation.Indy, ELocation.Columbus },
                                           new EEntity[] { EEntity.JobTool })]
```

LEMClaimAuthorizeAttribute is:

```
public class LEMClaimAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    const string POLICY_PREFIX = "LEMClaim";

    public ELocation[] Locations
    {
        get
        {
            if (Enum.TryParse(typeof(ELocation[]), Policy.Substring(POLICY_PREFIX.Length), out var locations) )
            {
                return (ELocation[]) locations;
            }

            return default(ELocation[]);
        }
        set
        {
            int[] intVals = Array.ConvertAll(value, val => (int)val);
            string arrayVal = string.Join(",", intVals);

            Policy = $"{POLICY_PREFIX}{arrayVal}";
        }
    }

//remaining code omitted for brevity
}
```

Custom Authorization Policy Provider:

```
public class LEMClaimPolicyProvider : IAuthorizationPolicyProvider
{
    const string POLICY_PREFIX = "LEMClaim";
    public DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider FallbackPolicyProvider { get; }

    public LEMClaimPolicyProvider(IOptions<AuthorizationOptions> options)
    {
        FallbackPolicyProvider = new DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider(options);
    }

    public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetDefaultPolicyAsync() => FallbackPolicyProvider.GetDefaultPolicyAsync();

    public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetPolicyAsync(string policyName)
    {
        if (!policyName.StartsWith(POLICY_PREFIX, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return FallbackPolicyProvider.GetPolicyAsync(policyName);

        string val = policyName.Substring(POLICY_PREFIX.Length);

        //CONVERT STRING TO INT[]
        int[] ia = val.Split(',').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();
        ELocation[] locations = (ELocation[])(object)ia;

        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder();
        policy.AddRequirements(new LEMClaimRequirement(locations));
        return Task.FromResult(policy.Build());


    }
}
```

1. This IS working for one enum array only.
2. How do I get it to work with other enum array parameters?
3. If there is a better way, in general, I'm all ears

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `Custom Policy Provider`, it uses `LEMClaimAuthorizeAttribute` to build the Policy, and then check the generated policys. For passing multiple parameters to `LEMClaimAuthorizeAttribute`, you need to pay attention to the process to generate the policy string and extract policys from the policystring.

For a solution, follow steps below:

- LEMClaimAuthorizeAttribute.cs

  ```
  public class LEMClaimAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
  {
  public LEMClaimAuthorizeAttribute(ELocation[] eLocations, EEntity[] eEntities = null)
  //public LEMClaimAuthorizeAttribute(ELocation[] eLocations)
  {
      Locations = eLocations;
      Entitys = eEntities;
  }
  const string POLICY_PREFIX_ELocation = "LEMClaim.ELocation";
  const string POLICY_PREFIX_EEntity = "LEMClaim.EEntity";

  public ELocation[] Locations
  {
      get
      {
          if (Enum.TryParse(typeof(ELocation[]), Policy.Substring(POLICY_PREFIX_ELocation.Length), out var locations))
          {
              return (ELocation[])locations;
          }

          return default(ELocation[]);
      }
      set
      {
          if (value != null)
          {
              int[] intVals = Array.ConvertAll(value, val => (int)val);
              string arrayVal = string.Join(",", intVals);

              Policy = Policy == null ? $"{POLICY_PREFIX_ELocation}{arrayVal}" : Policy + $";{POLICY_PREFIX_ELocation}{arrayVal}";
          }

      }
  }
  public EEntity[] Entitys
  {
      get
      {
          if (Enum.TryParse(typeof(EEntity[]), Policy.Substring(POLICY_PREFIX_EEntity.Length), out var locations))
          {
              return (EEntity[])locations;
          }

          return default(EEntity[]);
      }
      set
      {
          if (value != null)
          {
              int[] intVals = Array.ConvertAll(value, val => (int)val);
              string arrayVal = string.Join(",", intVals);
              Policy = Policy == null ? $"{POLICY_PREFIX_EEntity}{arrayVal}" : Policy + $";{POLICY_PREFIX_EEntity}{arrayVal}";
          }
      }
  }

  //remaining code omitted for brevity
   }
  ```
- LEMClaimRequirement.cs

  ```
  public class LEMClaimRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
  {
  public LEMClaimRequirement(ELocation[] eLocations, EEntity[] eEntities = null)
  {
      Locations = eLocations;
      Entitys = eEntities;
  }
  public ELocation[] Locations
  {
      get; set;
  }
  public EEntity[] Entitys
  {
      get; set;
  }
  }
  ```
- LEMClaimPolicyProvider.cs

  ```
  public class LEMClaimPolicyProvider : IAuthorizationPolicyProvider
  {
  const string POLICY_PREFIX = "LEMClaim";
  const string POLICY_PREFIX_ELocation = "LEMClaim.ELocation";
  const string POLICY_PREFIX_EEntity = "LEMClaim.EEntity";

  public DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider FallbackPolicyProvider { get; }

  public LEMClaimPolicyProvider(IOptions<AuthorizationOptions> options)
  {
      FallbackPolicyProvider = new DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider(options);
  }

  public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetDefaultPolicyAsync() => FallbackPolicyProvider.GetDefaultPolicyAsync();

  public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetPolicyAsync(string policyName)
  {
      if (!policyName.StartsWith(POLICY_PREFIX, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
          return FallbackPolicyProvider.GetPolicyAsync(policyName);
      var val = policyName.Split(";");
      //get locations
      int[] ia1 = val.FirstOrDefault(k => k.StartsWith(POLICY_PREFIX_ELocation, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                     .Substring(POLICY_PREFIX_ELocation.Length)
                     .Split(',').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();
      ELocation[] locations = (ELocation[])(object)ia1;
      int[] ia2 = val.FirstOrDefault(k => k.StartsWith(POLICY_PREFIX_EEntity, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                     ?.Substring(POLICY_PREFIX_EEntity.Length)
                     ?.Split(',').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();
      EEntity[] entitys = (EEntity[])(object)ia2;

      var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder();
      policy.AddRequirements(new LEMClaimRequirement(locations, entitys));
      return Task.FromResult(policy.Build());
  }
  }
  ```
- Use

  ```
      [LEMClaimAuthorize(new ELocation[] { ELocation.Indy, ELocation.Columbus })]
  public ActionResult One()
  {
      return View();
  }
  [LEMClaimAuthorize(new ELocation[] { ELocation.Indy, ELocation.Columbus }, new EEntity[] { EEntity.JobTool })]
  public ActionResult Two()
  {
      return View();
  }
  ```

Comment: For those reading this later, the only change I made to Tao Zhou's answer is the `LEMClaimPolicyProvider` casting to an enum array.  Like so:   `var locations = (ia1 != null) ? ia1.Cast<ELocation>().ToArray() : null;`

Comment: The `GetPolicyAsync` in `LEMClaimPolicyProvider` looks terribly awful to me. Isn't there a cleaner way to do it?