# ASP.NET Core - Dynamic Policy Based Authorization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm developing a application that's relatively large. I want to implement permission level authorization in my application. I've developed this code which works for one permission but doesn't work for multiple permission.

Here is sample code:
Below enum indicates features that my application will provide:

```
public enum CppFeature
{
    NotDefined = 0,

    DistributorManagement = 1,

    ChannelPartnerManagement = 2,
}
```

Below code indicates what permissions are supported in my application:

```
public enum CppPermission
{
    NotDefined = 0,
    View = 1,
    Invite = 2,
    Deactivate = 3,
    List = 4,
    Edit = 5,
    Create = 6,
    Approve = 7,
}
```

Finally a mapping is created in database which says which permissions are applicable in which feature...

```
|------------------------|------------------|
|      Feature           |     Permission   |
|------------------------|------------------|
|  DistributorManagement |       View       |
|------------------------|------------------|
|  DistributorManagement |      Invite      |
|------------------------|------------------|
|ChannelPartnerManagement|      Create      |
|------------------------|------------------|
```

A user then gets the ability to create a dynamic role and select permission from the mapping.

Later in my code, I've configured custom policies as below:

```
public class CppFeaturePermissionCheck
{
    public CppFeature Feature { get; set; }

    public List<CppPermission> Permission { get; set; }
}

public class CustomPolicyProvider : IAuthorizationPolicyProvider
{
    public CustomPolicyProvider (IOptions<AuthorizationOptions> options)
    {
        DefaultPolicyProvider = new DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider(options);
    }

    public DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider DefaultPolicyProvider { get; }

    public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetPolicyAsync(string policyName)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policyName))
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder();
            policy.AddRequirements(new CppAuthorizeRequirement(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CppFeaturePermissionCheck>>(policyName)));
            return Task.FromResult(policy.Build());
        }
        return DefaultPolicyProvider.GetPolicyAsync(policyName);
    }

    public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetDefaultPolicyAsync()
    {
        return DefaultPolicyProvider.GetDefaultPolicyAsync();
    }
}

public class CppAuthorizeRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public CppAuthorizeRequirement(List<CppFeaturePermissionCheck> userPermission)
    {
        UserPermissions = userPermission;
    }

    public List<CppFeaturePermissionCheck> UserPermissions { get; set; }
}

public class CppAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public CppAuthorizeAttribute(CppFeature feature, CppPermission permission)
        : this(new List<CppFeaturePermissionCheck>()
        {
            new CppFeaturePermissionCheck()
            {
                Feature = feature,
                Permission = new List<CppPermission>()
                {
                    permission,
                },
            },
        })
    {
    }
    // This ctor doesn't work since attributes can only have primitive types as parameter.
    public CppAuthorizeAttribute(List<CppFeaturePermissionCheck> featurePermissions)
    {
        Policy = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(featurePermissions, Formatting.None);
    }
}

[CppAuthorize(CppFeature.ChannelPartnerManagement, CppPermission.View)]
[HttpPost("channelpartnerlist")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PartnerList([FromBody]ChannelPartnerListRequestModel_V1 model)
    {
        try
        {
            //some work.                
        }
        catch (CPPException ioe)
        {

        }
    }
```

The problem is:
1. The attribute doesn't support parameter type of Array, List or Dictionary which would allow me to specify multiple permissions

Is there a better way by which I can specify whether a specific action is supported for specific permission in specific feature?

Comment: For passing multiple parameters to `CppAuthorizeAttribute `, you need to pay attention to the process to generate the policy string and extract policys from the policystring. You could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52970354/asp-net-core-pass-several-parameters-to-custom-authorization-policy-provider) which pass one or more enum array parameters.

Comment: @XueliChen  that doesn't work... The difference is - in that specific thread the parameter type is Array of ENUM where as in my case, I've two enums and each of them have dependency... See class CppFeaturePermissionCheck